# What would happen if a variable were manipulated more than once at the exact same time? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Assume one asynchronous function which returns the result of a short sum:

```
var data = 0;
function asyncFunction() { data += 1; }
```

Is it possible for this function to be executed asynchronously more than one time at the exact same time?  Assuming this function was called asynchronously two times AND they were executed at the exact same time, could it be possible data would be equal to 1 and not 2?

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the proposed link.  The item being linked does represent one case of a data race but only answers that specific data race question.  What we'd like to know here is if there is any possible situation which might result in a data race condition in javascript.

Comment: Impossible in JS. There are no data races.

Comment: No way JS is single threaded

Comment: @squint Thank you for the replies.   Please add as an answer so I can solve the question.  I Google'd some keywords from your responses and found the following article:  https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/06/17/no-there-are-no-race-conditions-in-javascript/  Appreciate the quick help.